# Разделение FormRequest на части (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, валидация

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста советом.
Имеются несколько FormRequest для разных форм. На двух формах возможны одинаковые компоненты, например, Адрес или Паспорт. Каким образом можно вынести набор правил для этих компонентов, чтобы не дублировать их в каждом FormRequest?
Предусмотрено ли это фреймворком или как это можно красиво обыграть?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, Вы можете создать массив с правилами внутри config (например rules.php), и затем мержить правила в классе валидации с правилами в конфиге.

```
public function rules()
{
    $array = [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];

    return array_merge($array, config('rules.some_key'));
}
```